# Admin page not found - 404

Tags: magento2, admin, css, 404-page

I just installed Magento 2, it shown the success page result however the admin folder is not found.

Also the main page does not seem to be ok, seems like css is not in place, there is no menu... just their text and images.

Didn't find any error message.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache of Nginx? Also, do you havve localhost as your hostname?

Answer (score 0):

For admin, please check the `/app/etc/env.php` file for `backend=>frontname` for example `admin_mm0iwi`. Then navigate to `<your host>/admin_mm0iwi`. If this is not working, please check if you have mod rewrite turned on in apache. Also, it is recommended to NOT have `localhost` as your hostname, since some browsers have issues with cookies.

For no css, please run the `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` on your console.

Comment: How to turned on the mod rewrite on apache?.

Comment: I found: > nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ++find >>follow (AllowOverride none) ++and change it >> (AllowOverride All)

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with this issue and managed to solve it with the help of [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Here's where it comes down to:

**First: enable mod_rewrite:**

1. open terminal
2. enable mod_rewrite
3. restart apache2

> sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2

**Secondly: adjust your .conf file:**

1. locate your .conf file
2. add the `<Directory ...>` code
3. restart apache2

> ls /etc/apache2/sites-available
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Add this code below the  tag:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

**And now you should be able to surf to your own admin page**

*Note: you'll probably use the `000-default.conf`, unless you have set up a different VirtualHost. In that case you need to change the `000-default.conf` with your own VirtualHost.conf file and change the `/var/www/html` to point to your own public_html directory.*

*Note2: use `ctrl-o` in nano to save a file and `ctrl-x` to close it.*